# Does this phrase in "Knocking On Heaven's Door", refer to gravitons?

Tags: gravity, experimental-physics, dark-matter, large-hadron-collider

This is an extract from [Knocking On Heaven's Door](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061723738), by Randall (2011)

> The suprising fact is that if you have a stable particle whose mass corresponds to the weak energy scale that the LHC will explore and whose interactions also involve particles with that energy, it's relic density  will be in the right ball parkpark to be dark matter.

I fairly much follow her point, except for the phrase **whose interactions also involve particles with that energy** and I wonder: is she referring to gravitons, when she talks of particles in the highlighted phrase? I am confused as to whether she is speaking of the original stable particle, or a force carrying entity?

I self study and have not got the background or experience to think of anything more likely when possible dark matter is invoked (so as far as I know, it's *only* gravitons that she could be referring to when dark matter is involved).

If anyone is good enough to explain this point, or a basic misunderstanding or wrong assumption of mine, this would also be appreciated, as I will have learnt something from this question.

I am not too concerned with her point about what the LHC may or may not discover in the future, as I can research this aspect myself.

Comment: "right ball parkpark..."?

Comment: Must be hard for the editors and readers...